# Magento - serve cached content from Varnish while requesting a new object from the backend

Tags: magento, caching, varnish

I'm currently running Varnish 7.2 in front of Magento 2.4. I generated the correct Varnish config using Magento's builtin config.
Everything is working fine, including caching.

As expected, Magento purges the cache in Varnish once a value in the backend is changed.

Unfortunately, that results in a slow response upon the next request.

I want that the first request after purging/invalidating the cache still serves the old value, while fetching the new value from the backend, putting it into the Varnish cache and delivering it upon the next request as a HIT on the cache.

Varnish config (generated by Magento)

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "web-host01.example.com;
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "web-host01.example.com";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts > 0) {
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass customer, shopping cart, checkout
    if (req.url ~ "/customer" || req.url ~ "/checkout") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(health_check.php)$") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # Bypass authenticated GraphQL requests without a X-Magento-Cache-Id
    if (req.url ~ "/graphql" && !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if ((req.url !~ "/graphql" || !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) && req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id);

        # When the frontend stops sending the auth token, make sure users stop getting results cached for logged-in users
        if (req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
            hash_data("Authorized");
        }
    }

    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }

    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s that are not marked as private
    if (beresp.status != 200 &&
            beresp.status != 404 &&
            beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

   # If the cache key in the Magento response doesn't match the one that was sent in the request, don't cache under the request's key
   if (bereq.url ~ "/graphql" && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id != beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
      set beresp.ttl = 0s;
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    if (!resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

varnishlog after purging

```
*   << BeReq    >> 65548     
-   Begin          bereq 65547 fetch
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1666813603.131250 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /example-req-url
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Host: staging.example.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   BereqHeader    Referer: https://staging.example.com/path/to/something
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
-   BereqHeader    Cookie: COOKIES
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.10.10
-   BereqHeader    Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   BereqHeader    grace: none
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 65548
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1666813603.131283 0.000032 0.000032
-   Timestamp      Connected: 1666813603.131767 0.000517 0.000484
-   BackendOpen    27 web-host01 172.19.25.32 80 172.19.25.34 36108 connect
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1666813603.131833 0.000583 0.000065
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1666813604.043211 0.911961 0.911378
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   BerespHeader   Pragma: cache
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=3UR6dQy6ODHqy3w3; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=2627569dcdbeca193d32905c799896fce3eeb169; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:44 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cms_b_custom_navigation_links,cms_b_header_top_message,cms_b_header_top_quicklink,cms_b_page_bottom_steps,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_outer,cms_b_page_bottom_faq,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_background,cms_b_prefooter_block,cms_b_footer_bo
-   BerespHeader   Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src fonts.gstatic.com https://widgets.trustedshops.com https://integrations.etrusted.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.c
-   BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 19070
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   TTL            RFC 86400 10 0 1666813604 1666813604 1666813603 1666900003 86400 cacheable
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL 86400 259200 0 1666813604 cacheable
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: form_key=3UR6dQy6ODHqy3w3; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=2627569dcdbeca193d32905c799896fce3eeb169; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:44 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1666813604.043276 0.912026 0.000065
-   Filters         gunzip esi_gzip
-   BerespUnset    Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespUnset    Content-Length: 19070
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   Fetch_Body     3 length -
-   Gzip           G F E 87119 19971 80 159688 159698
-   Gzip           U F - 19070 87119 80 80 152490
-   BackendClose   27 web-host01 recycle
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1666813604.050210 0.918960 0.006933
-   Length         19971
-   BereqAcct      1377 0 1377 6858 19070 25928
-   End            

*   << Request  >> 65547     
-   Begin          req 65546 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1666813603.130872 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1666813603.130872 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       192.168.10.10 3330 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /example-req-url
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: staging.example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Referer: https://staging.example.com/path/to/something
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: __delivery_area_postcode=00000; __delivery_area_storeId=3; store=beelitz; form_key=3UR6dQy6ODHqy3w3; mage-messages=; mage-cache-storage={}; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation={}; recently_viewed_product={}; recently_viewed_product_previous={
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.10.10
-   ReqHeader      Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /example-req-url
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   ExpBan         3 banned lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 65548 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1666813604.050238 0.919365 0.919365
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Expires: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   RespHeader     Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cms_b_custom_navigation_links,cms_b_header_top_message,cms_b_header_top_quicklink,cms_b_page_bottom_steps,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_outer,cms_b_page_bottom_faq,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_background,cms_b_prefooter_block,cms_b_footer_bo
-   RespHeader     Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src fonts.gstatic.com https://widgets.trustedshops.com https://integrations.etrusted.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.c
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 65547
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT
-   RespHeader     Grace: none
-   RespUnset      Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespUnset      Expires: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespUnset      X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cms_b_custom_navigation_links,cms_b_header_top_message,cms_b_header_top_quicklink,cms_b_page_bottom_steps,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_outer,cms_b_page_bottom_faq,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_background,cms_b_prefooter_block,cms_b_footer_bo
-   RespUnset      Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 65547
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1666813604.050321 0.919449 0.000083
-   Filters         esi
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Link           req 65549 esi 1
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1666813604.050855 0.919982 0.000533
-   ReqAcct        1328 0 1328 5467 23108 28575
-   End            

*   << Session  >> 65546     
-   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
-   SessOpen       192.168.10.10 3330 a0 172.19.25.34 80 1666813603.129864 24
-   Link           req 65547 rxreq
-   SessClose      TX_EOF 0.921
-   End
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the open source version of Varnish doesn't support soft bans. Soft purges on individual objects are supported (see https://varnish-cache.org/docs/7.2/reference/vmod_purge.html#int-soft-duration-ttl-duration-grace-duration-keep).

The only way to do soft purging on multiple matching objects would be through `vmod_ykey`, which is part of Varnish Enterprise. (see https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/ykey/#purge)

Comment: Deleting one object using a soft purge is enough. Could you provide an example on how to implement it?
I tried implementing that PURGE requests result in a purge.soft(0s,300s) action in vcl_hit and vcl_miss, but the cache was still on MISS after changing the object.

When calling the function in vcl_recv no cache is cleared at all, not even after 300s.

Comment: I'd replace `return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));` with `purge.soft(0s,300s);` to allow individual objects being "soft purged" when the `X-Magento-Tags-Pattern` and `X-Pool` headers aren't set. Don't hesitate to add any error messages or relevant `varnishlog` output to your question if this doesn't work for you.